# Does a group overlap another group?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm not a native speaker and I want to describe the following case:

There is an Active Directory group and another one. Let's say "Managers" and "Janitors". Both of these groups have the same members.

So~, do these groups `overlap` each over, or do they `intersect`? Or is there any other word?

In Russian I'd say "пересекаться". As in "группы пересекаются"

Edit to clarify the question:

E.g. 'Sally' and 'Harry' are members of Managers group, 'Jack' and 'Sally' are members of Janitors group. So do these groups `overlap` or `intersect` or `something else`?

**(note that 'Sally' is a member of both of these groups).**

Comment: Are they the same members or their number is the same?

Comment: @Carlo_R. for example 'Sally' and 'Harry' are members of *Managers* group, 'Jack' and 'Sally' are members of *Janitors* group. So do these groups `overlap` or `intersect` or something else? ^_^ (note that 'Sally' is a member of both of these groups).

Comment: "Managers and Janitors have some members in common."

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, out of math contexts, use overlap.

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't really understand downvotes though. Anyone to explain? Is this `too localized`, `not a real question` or what?

Comment: bah, generally speaking, people vote down questions which are off-topic or show no research efforts. It is worthy noting that too basic questions can be asked on English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com), the new SE proposal tailored for people learning English as second language.

Comment: And in maths contexts, use _sets_ instead of _groups_ in cases like this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous ways to say that two groups have some members in common:
• The “Managers” and “Janitors” groups overlap
• The groups have an overlap
• The groups intersect
• The groups have a non-empty intersection
• The groups have some members in common
• Some people are in both groups

Different people will choose different phrases, depending on preferences and circumstances.  All of the above forms are acceptable but I think I'd use the last form instead of speaking of overlaps and intersections.

Comment: "Non-empty intersection" is accurate, but would be unlikely to be used among people who are not mathematicians. "Some people are in both groups" is probably the most clear and unambiguos. Two groups could "overlap" or "intersect" in ways other than the list of members, for example the list of responsibilities, or physical locations occupied.